# a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $C([a,b])$ be the collection of all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that continuous on $[a,b]$.

It is known that if $f\in C([a,b])$ then $f$ is continuous on every sub-interval of $[a,b]$.

I curious whether the converse is also true, that is if $C([c,d])\subseteq C([a,b]) $ then $[c,d]$ must be subset of $[a,b]$.

I cannot prove it and show the counter example.

Comment: Did you mean that $C([a,b])$ is *the* collection of continuous function etc...?

Comment: If $f\in C([c,d])$ then f is a function from $[c,d]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so if $f\in C([a,b])$ obviously $[c,d]=[a,b]$

Comment: To expand on Sebastian's comment: technically the containment $C([a, b]) \subseteq C([c, d])$ is not true if $[c, d] \subsetneq [a, b]$: the domains do not match. Could you rephrase the question to address that formal issue? E.g.: if every function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous on $[a, b]$ is also continuous on $[c, d]$, then $[c, d] \subseteq [a, b]$.

Comment: To all. Thanks for the comment. Ishall edit my question to make clear

Comment: What you stated as the converse is **not** the converse and makes no sense even if we ignore the technical point *Sebastian* raised, since for any $[c,d] \supseteq [a,b]$, a function that is continuous on $[c,d]$ is obviously continuous on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a function $f$ on interval $[a,b]$, the converse to:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous on any subinterval of $[a,b]$.

is **not** what you wrote (which depending on your intended interpretation is either false or does not make sense), but is:

> If $f$ is continuous on any subinterval of $[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

which is obviously true (think about it), and so is useless. More useful is:

> If $c \in [a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous on $[a,c]$ and continuous on $[c,b]$, then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

which you can try to prove.

Comment: I'd say that what he wrote is not false, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @tomasz: It doesn't make sense as per *Adayah*'s comment, but if we ignore that technical point then it makes sense and is false. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure that if we interpret is as Adayah has suggested, then it is actually true (and easy to see). More generally, this remains true if you replace $[a,b]$ with any $G_\delta$ set (and $[c,d]$ with *any* set). Then again, for non-closed $X\subseteq {\bf R}$, the restriction from ${\bf R}$ is not onto, so maybe it doesn't make sense to generalise like that.

Comment: @tomasz: The version stated by the asker, interpreted that way, is still not the same as the one *Adayah* stated at the end of his comment. *Adayah*'s version is true, of course.